# .net maui blazor project msix install in window for all users

Tags: .net, maui, maui-blazor, maui-windows

I have a windows application developed using .NET MAUI Blazor application to manage Users and their data.

I have generated a MSIX package with a temporary test Certificate.

Now I have one Administrator account through which I am installing this MSIX package.

My Requirement:

I also have multiple Users that will be using this installed application via their own local Windows accounts.
I want to install application in administrator account and then It will available for all users.

I tried:

1. Add uap:SupportedUsersmultiple</uap:SupportedUsers> in Package.appxmanifest not worked

any idea how we can do it.

appreciate your response

Comment: Try this: [Using Administrator Status To Install A Program In Win10](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/using-administrator-status-to-install-a-program-in/08569dd8-7539-4dd7-adb5-2a0f91c564d5)?